# Have multiple elements in sqlite column

Tags: python, sqlite

How can i add multiple elements for a single column in a row:

Say i have a column, topic, which can have infinitely many elements inside:

```
topics = ['Particle Physics,'Karaoke','jazz']
```

I have a statement in sqlite:

```
def UpdateElement(new_user,new_topic):
    new_topic = new_topic + "; "
    querycurs.execute('''UPDATE First_Data SET topic = (?) WHERE user = (?)''', (new_topic, new_user))
```

However this will allow only one element at a time to exist under the topic column. How can you edit the code so that it can add another given element to the current topic.

If in the table topic = ['Math'], then i could make it into topic = '[Math; Python']. This way i can use simple python .join statement to split it.

Comment: If you're using SQLite, have SQLite handle the joins.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

With a text field you can store anything.  You could store the list as semi-colon delimited string or as a json object string.  You could also pickle the list and store it as a base64 string. The problem with all of these solutions is that you lose a level of access to your data.  To count how many users have like Jazz topic, you need to read/split the text field...or use some more complicated LIKE statement.

Since you are using SQL, you may want to consider normalizing your data to include a *Topic* table, a *User* table, and a **cross-walk table with foreign keys to your users and topics** to enforce the many-to-many relationship. While its a bit more to setup, but it can be simpler to update when user topics change.